# Getting “Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file” in local

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have the below pom.xml which is fine.I am able to generate jacoco.exec and see the coverage in sonarqube.But the problem is when i am run the code in local (my laptop). `target/site` folder is not generated and jacoco reports are not generated jacoco.exe is generated  is starting folder of my app and not in `target` folder.
[image]
How can i solve this issue for local ?

I get the below error when i run `maven install or maven test`

```
Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file
```

I have maven spring boot application

pom.xml

```
 <properties>
        <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>
    
    -- snipper of jacoco plugin tag
     <configuration>
            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
            
        </configuration>
```

Comment: That value of sonar.jacoco.reportPath seems odd.  Why are you attempting to write/read from the parent directory?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr then what value should i give .it works for me when i run bamboo plan .i get the code coverage in sonarqube.I tried changing the value to `<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>` .This value worked fine in local but i started getting 0 coverage in sonarqube.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a long time ago, we replaced the use of the "jacoco.exec" file with the use of the "jacoco.xml" file.  The former is supposedly deprecated now.

We set the following properties:

- sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths: ${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml
- jacoco.path: ${basedir}/target/jacoco_report

In the jacoco plugin configuration, have the following:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                    after unit tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

In the surefire plugin configuration, we have this:

```
<argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
```

Comment: whats the value for `${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}` for your project?

Comment: I don't know. We don't set it or use it.

Comment: M.karr i tried  your config.It works well in local but when i try it on sonarqube server its showing 0%coverage

Comment: Ok. Verify that when you do the local build you can open "/target/jacoco_report/index.html" in the browser. That will show the coverage results. That's the next thing to check.

Comment: yes thats what i meant whne i saiud it works in local.I can see coverage in local but in sonarqube ut shows 0

Comment: Next things to check: How many unit tests does SonarQube list?  Zero, or about the number you would expect?  The answer to that takes us in different directions to diagnose this. Also verify that "target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml" is present in your CI server workspace.

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using?  Report that in the sonarsource forum also.

Comment: The other problem is that you haven't shown how you run the scanner.

Comment: I think you are right. Problem might be with how I am executing. We use bamboo.
Sonarqube version 6.7.1 . For maven task in bamboo only command we have is `-Dsonar.scm.disabled=true`.Nothing else.How  to verify if `target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml`  is present  in CI worspace ?

Comment: 6.7.1 is quite old. Some of this might not work in that version. I have no idea how to see files in the bamboo workspace. I haven't used it for years.

Comment: ok just 1 question can we pass `target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml` as maven command.I can try that

Comment: You can set properties on the mvn command line with - D.